# How to remote access computer through Excel VBA

Tags: vba

Is it possible to run an Excel VBA, through selections on some form controls on the Excel sheet, write to a file in a remote machine? Both machines can only be connected through internet.

I am not asking for code but conceptually how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your post mentions only two computers and does not mention what kind of file or if machine receiving file will only read the file.

So, making the easy assumptions that it's a csv file and the receiver machine will only read said file, you could use ftp.

This [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bvba%5D%20title:ftp) should get you started there.

Of course, you would have to set up an ftp server on the receiving machine and open the ftp ports on the computer and the router.

If you're looking for a way to open/edit Office files remotely using only VBA, good luck.  :)

That type of task I delegate to Sharepoint.